# How to return future from another class?

Tags: flutter, dart, httpclient

Community.
I need help.
In main.dart I am calling a future function which is in another class.

```
 @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
          
          getCall();
         
    
      }
```

and get call is like.

```
Future<List> futureloinlevel;
    AsynFunctions ayncla=new AsynFunctions();

    void getCall(){
  try{
    futureloinlevel=  ayncla.fetchloginlevel("StoreLogin", lang, context);
  } catch (err) {
    print('Caught error: $err');
  }
}
```

The function in the `AsynFunctions` class is

```
    Future<List<Result>> fetchloginlevel(String screenname,String lang,BuildContext context) async {
                 var lname="ShowScreenLabels?ScreenName=";
  
              List<Result>resultlist;
   try{
    var clien=await genrateClient(context);
var link="$v$lname$screenname&LangType="+lang;
print(link);


   var request = await clien.getUrl(
        Uri.parse(link));
   
    request.headers.set("authorization", StoreConfig.basicAuth);
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    

    print(response.toString());
     response
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
       
        .listen((contents) async {

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      
      print(contents);

      userMap = await jsonDecode(contents)as Map;

      var uer= LoginLevel.fromJson(userMap);

      resultlist=uer.result;
     

      


    } else {
      
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }

        });
   
    return resultlist;

   }on Exception catch (e) {
     print('error caught: $e');
   }


  }
```

This function returns nothing. How do I return future list from here?
Null is shown on calling the function.

Comment: Can any body tell me i am working on it from 6 days.?

Comment: result of command print(contents) is null?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fetchloginlevel()` is working correctly and fetching the data you want to consume, you just need to convert `getCall()` to `async` method and `await` for your result like this:

```
void getCall() async {
  try{
    futureloinlevel = await ayncla.fetchloginlevel("StoreLogin", lang, context);
  } catch (err) {
    print('Caught error: $err');
  }
}
```

Comment: But it is not producing result too. NomethodSuchOpertaor. Tried calling..[]. I Think it fetchloinetail linin as stream and call two time. first time accept by server and second time got data but return null on first time. So i am confusing.